# Difference between regular and smooth curve?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, curves

I have question about curves in space.
What is the difference between regular curve and smooth curve?

Comment: smooth curve means the parametrization is differentiable whereas regularity requires the derivative to be non-zero.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the curve is defined by the parametric equations

$(x,y,z) = (f(t), g(t), h(t))$, where $t \in [a,b]$

The curve is a **smooth curve** if the derivatives $f'$, $g'$, $h'$ exist and are continuous in $[a,b]$

The curve is a **regular curve** or a **regular smooth curve**, if it's smooth and also the three derivatives $f'$, $g'$, $h'$ are not simultaneously zero for any $t_0 \in [a,b]$